# How can I get all the comments/reviews from a google maps place using puppeteer? (I dont get all of them because page is scrollable)

Tags: node.js, google-maps, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape comments/reviews from a place I search using Puppeteer. I have 2 problems:

1. I only get 16 comments/reviews from the current page, when in reality I want ALL the comments/reviews (in this case 62 comments or even more depending on my search) but I think the problem comes from the page being scrollable.
2. I am getting an error when I scrape reviews that have no comments in google maps saying:

   ```
   "(node:13184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
   at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:9:38"
   ```

   , and I am not sure how to get rid of that everytime there is a review that has a NULL comment (I have some code almost at the end trying to solve the NULL comments but doesn't work and I tried a few other ways that didn't work either).

Below is my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer'); // Require the Package we need...

let scrape = async () => { // Prepare scrape...

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disabled-setuid-sandbox']}); // Prevent non-needed issues for *NIX
    const page = await browser.newPage(); // Create request for the new page to obtain...

    const busqueda = 'Alitas+del+Cadillac+Tumbaco';
    const Url = `https://www.google.com/maps/search/${busqueda}`;

    const buscar = '.section-result';
    const click1 = '.widget-pane-link';
    const cajaTexto = '#searchboxinput';

    const comentarioLength = 'section-review-text';
    const comentarios = 'div.section-review:nth-child(Index) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(4)';

    console.log(comentarioLength);

    //const comentario = 'div.section-review:nth-child(INDEX) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(4)';

    // Replace with your Google Maps URL... Or Test the Microsoft one...
    //await page.goto('https://www.google.com/maps/place/Microsoft/@36.1275216,-115.1728651,17z/data=!3m1!5s0x80c8c416a26be787:0x4392ab27a0ae83e0!4m7!3m6!1s0x80c8c4141f4642c5:0x764c3f951cfc6355!8m2!3d36.1275216!4d-115.1706764!9m1!1b1');

    await page.goto(Url); // Define the Maps URL to Scrape...
    await page.waitFor(2*1000); // In case Server has JS needed to be loaded...

    await page.click(buscar); //busco caja de texto*/

    await page.waitForNavigation();
    await page.waitFor(2*1000);

    await page.click(click1);

    await page.waitForNavigation();
    await page.waitFor(2*1000);

    console.log(page.url());

    console.log("3");

    await page.evaluate(_ => { // This is just a test, don't really need this!

    });

    await page.waitFor(2*1000);

    console.log('how many?', (await page.$$('.section-review-text')).length);

    //div.section-result:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > h3:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)

    let listLength = await page.evaluate((sel) => {
        window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
        return document.getElementsByClassName(sel).length;
    }, comentarioLength);

    console.log(listLength);

    for (let i = 1; i <= listLength; i++) {

        let selectorComentarios = comentarios.replace("Index", i);

        const result = await page.evaluate((sel) => { // Let's create variables and store values...

            return document.querySelector(sel).innerText;

        }, selectorComentarios);

        if(!result){
            continue;
        }

        console.log(i+result);

    }

    /*await page.evaluate(_ => {
        window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight)
    })*/

    browser.close(); // Close the Browser...
    return result; // Return the results with the Review...
};

scrape().then((value) => { // Scrape and output the results...


console.log(value); // Yay, output the Results...
});
```

Comment: You have to let the code navigate the infinite scroll in Google Maps. It may be against Google's TOC but they cannot stop you from downloading it and using it. The courts have ruled that whatever is scrape able can be scraped.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the first problem you need to handle an infinite scroll by adding a function like:

```js
async function scrollPage(page, scrollContainer) {
  let lastHeight = await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("${scrollContainer}").scrollHeight`);
  while (true) {
    await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("${scrollContainer}").scrollTo(0, document.querySelector("${scrollContainer}").scrollHeight)`);
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000);
    let newHeight = await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("${scrollContainer}").scrollHeight`);
    if (newHeight === lastHeight) {
      break;
    }
    lastHeight = newHeight;
  }
}
```

In this function, the first argument is the Puppeteer `page` and the second is
a scrollable HTML element (in this case it has classname `.DxyBCb`). This function checks the element's current `scrollHeight`, then scroll to this height and checks `scrollHeight` again. If it is changed by loading new elements the function repeats scroll again.

The second problem in this part of code:

```js
return document.querySelector(sel).innerText;
```

You need to handle cases in which an element with the selector `sel` isn't found on the page. You can use [optional chining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) which returns `undefined` instead of throwing an error and add some text when it happens:

```js
return document.querySelector(sel)?.innerText || `Element with selector ${sel} not found on the page`;
```

And now if the searching selector is absent your evaluate function returns the text after `||`.

Blog post with more detailed information that is beyond the scope of your question: [web Scraping Google Maps reviews with Nodejs](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-google-maps-reviews-with-nodejs).

Answer (score 0):

This is against Terms of services of Google Maps Platform.

Have a look at paragraph 3.2.4 (Restrictions Against Misusing the Services). It reads

> (a)  ***No Scraping***.  Customer will not extract, export, scrape, or cache Google Maps Content for use outside the Services. For example, Customer will not:(i) pre-fetch, index, store, reshare, or rehost Google Maps Content outside the services; (ii) bulk download geocodes; (iii) **copy business names, addresses, or user reviews;** or (iv) use Google Maps Content with text-to-speech services. Caching is permitted for certain Services as described in the Maps Service Specific Terms.

source: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#3-license

Sorry for being bearer of bad news.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning something I wasnt aware of. Its sad I cant use it for educational purposes :(.